# Could not create database in rails. "ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: FATAL: role "jonathanreiser" does not exist"

Tags: postgresql

I am attempting to create a database for a Rails application and I get the following error message `ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: FATAL:  role "jonathanreiser" does not exist`. I am running Postgres 9.6 on OS X El Capitan, Version 10.11.15.

I saw there were similar questions on StackOverflow, but I tried implementing their answers with no success. For example, `sudo -u postgres createuser jonathanreiser` or `sudo su - postgres` does not work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the error (or output) you get when you execute [`createuser`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-createuser.html)? Have you tried using also the `--pwprompt` or `--interactive` options?

Comment: The error I get when executing `createuser` is `sudo: unknown user: postgres`. I haven't used `--pwprompt` or `--interactive` options, how would I go about doing that? Also, what username are we referring to here? Is it the username that I sign onto my macbook with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure database.yml with below code:

```
default: &default

adapter: postgresql
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  username : username //pg username
  password : password //pg password

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db_name

test:
  <<: *default
  database: db_name

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db_name
```

then run command to create database:

```
rake db:create
```

Comment: This did not work for me. Question though, what is the database name I should be referring to? Is it the name of one of the tables in my migration files, or is it from someplace else? Also, is the username the name I sign on to my macbook with?

Comment: In database name, you can write any name for database.
In username, when you install postgres and create user that name is the username.

Answer (score 1):

Run

`rails db:create`

or

`rake db:create`

Then you can run `rails db:migrate`